# How can I add a class using jQuery in this loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, loops, attr

I would like to add a class to each of my cardCount elements using jQuery.

```
if (i == 13 || i == 26 || i == 39) {
for (ii=0; ii<13; ii++){
cardCount += "<span>" + cardOrder[ii] + "</span>"}
```

Thank you.

UPDATED WORKING:

```
    for (ii=0; ii<13; ii++){
        cardCreate += "<span class=" + changeClass + '>' + cardOrder[ii] + "</span>";
    }
```

Comment: `cardCount` Elements? In HTML `class='classNameHere'`. In JavaScript `Element.className = 'classNameHere'`. In jQuery `jQueryElement.addClass('classNameHere')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use jquery after all you may try this:

```
$("span").addClass("myClass");
```

Note that the code above will apply the class "myClass" to all of your spans.

But, do this is  better:

```
cardCount += "<span class='myClass'>" + cardOrder[ii] + "</span>"}
```

Comment: Your first code will add the class to all spans anywhere in the DOM, not just the ones in `cardCount`.

Comment: Yes, I know but in his example he don't provide us any context or identifier for that spans. I didn't want to change his code so he can understand it.

Comment: @imazzara yea sorry I don't know what is to much or to little code on here I am still a noob. Anyways thanks for the help it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use jQuery for this, you could simply add the class in the raw html.

```
if (i == 13 || i == 26 || i == 39) {
for (ii=0; ii<13; ii++){
cardCount += "<span class='myclass'>" + cardOrder[ii] + "</span>"}
```

Comment: Thank you. yea I have just been trying to use jQuery as much as possible because I am so rusty.